# How to DRY code in controllers and helpers for rendering the right way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rendering, dry

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.13 and I would like to DRY (Don't Reapeat Yourself) my code in controllers e views. That is, at this time...

... in my controller I have:

```
# ArticlesController

def index
  @articles = ...
  ...
  case ...
  when ... then render(:partial => 'partial_for_index', :object => @articles, :as => 'articles', ...)
  else render :index
  end
end

def show
  @article = ...
  ...
  case ...
  when ... then render(:partial => 'partial_for_show', :object => @article, :as => 'article', ...)
  else render :show
  end
end
```

... in my helper I have:

```
# ArticlesHelper

def render_partial_for_index(articles, ...)
  articles.map { |article| render_partial_for_show(article, ...) }.join('').html_safe
end

def render_partial_for_show(article, ...)
  render(:partial => 'partial_for_show', :object => article, :as => 'article', ...)
end
```

... in my views I have:

```
# articles/_partial_for_index.html.erb
<%= render_partial_for_index(@articles, ...) %>

# articles/_partial_for_show.html.erb
<%= article.title %> created at <%= article.created_at %>
```

In order to DRY my code I thought to use helper methods directly in controller (*note*: I know this approach breaks the MVC pattern but it is just an example of what I aim to make and should make the issue to be more understandable), this way:

```
# ArticlesController

include ArticlesHelper

def index
  @articles = ...
  ...
  case ...
  when ... then render_partial_for_index(@articles, ...)
  else render :index
  end
end

def show
  @article = ...
  ...
  case ...
  when ... then render_partial_for_show(@article, ...)
  else render :show
  end
end
```

This way I can delete the `_partial_for_index.html.erb` view file since it is not used anymore and the code is *DRYed* and *consistent* throughout the application. However, whilst the controller `show` action works as expected, the controller `index` action does not since I get the `DoubleRenderError` error because multiple `render` methods run in the `render_partial_for_index` helper method.

In few words, I would like to use as less as possible statements for rendering. How can / should I DRY my code in order to reach what I aim to make? That is, how can I make it to work by keeping availability of `render_partial_for_index` and `render_partial_for_show` methods in views and controllers the right way?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I don't like your controller because it mixes the logic which should belong to view, and the render_blah methods make things unnecessarily complex.

I prefer this style:

```
# ArticlesController
def index
  @articles = ...
end

def show
  @article  = ...
end

# views/articles/index.html.erb
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <%= render partial: 'article', locals: {article: article}
<% end %>

# views/articles/show.html.erb
<%= render partial: 'article', locals: {article: @article}

# views/articles/_article.html.erb
<%= article.title %>
<%= article.body  %>
# blah blah
```

Same effect. DRYer code. Cleaner logic. No helpers needed.

Comment: Partial templates I mentioned in the question are used more and more in my application and so I extracted the related rendering code in helper methods in order to do not repeat the whole `render partial: ...` statement and to keep things consistent. Since the exactly same rendering is needed in controller actions (and I'd not repeat the `render partial: ...`) then I would like to use the same statement even there. *Note*: The question'd focus on the organization and accessibility of methods and not the content of view files.

Comment: So, how can I keep logic sepated but DRY it?

Comment: I updated the question. Maybe things are more clear because I would like to make that...

Comment: There is a `_article` partial for your reusing everywhere. If you use a helper, you still need to feed it with variable. I doubt that would be simpler than using `render` directly

Comment: Say you have a widget to show recent articles, you can make a widget partial or widget helper, which calls this partial. Besides, I don't understand what are the cases in your controller, looks not a convention.

Comment: How you can read in the updated question, in controller actions there is a `case ... when` statement that should make it more explicit when I need to render partials, and so why I would DRY code. My solution with helper methods is just an example of what I aim to make and should make the issue to be more understandable.

Comment: `case 'foo then template = "f"; case bar then template = "b"; render partial: template;`